# How would I go about including or excluding certain areas using grid depending on @Media queries?

Tags: html, css, grid

If for example I have 5 'areas' wrapped in my HTML container tags but I only wish to use 4 of them then I'm below @media (min-width: 768px) for mobile devices.

I can't seem to comprehend a way to exclude an area. Being able to do this would prove very helpful especially when I only want one advert bar on the page at once but in certain @media queries it's horizontal and in others it's vertical. It'd be very handy to be able to mix and match areas in such a way.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <advert></advert>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
```

In this above example imagine I'd like to use advert when below @media (min-width: 768px) but use aside instead when above.

CSS so far:

```
@media only screen /* Tablet */
  and (min-width: 768px) {
    body  {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }

@media screen /* Desktop/Laptop */
  and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .container  {
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "advert main"
      "footer footer"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible to change html based on media queries, but you could use `<div id='ad'>`, and then change its orientation (vertical/horizontal) with media queries and e.g. flexbox.

Or you could change it in the grid like this:

```
/* Standard */
.container  {
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "advert main"
    "footer footer"
}
/* Tablet */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body  {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .container  {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 150px 10fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "advert"
      "main"
      "footer"
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh! very cool! thanks! There's another way of using grid am I right? In a more block-based method rather than this abstract area method? I.E grid-area: 1/1/2/4. Would that make this easier?

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference, but you can of course change the grid in a media query. You could make the ad display horizontally on mobile by changing it in the grid.

Comment: Annoying how I'm not able to change the area to another <background-image: URL()> under another @media

Comment: If the update answers your question, I'd really appreciate an upvote and accept of the answer! If not, let me know.